# Deep recursion of lambda

Tags: c++, lambda

I have a program composed of N level loops. But N is not fixed, so I take template to help. Following is the logic.

```
#include <type_traits>

void do_something1() {}
void do_something2() {}
enum Case { one, two };
struct loop {
    template<int N, Case case_, typename Lambda>
    std::enable_if_t < (0 < N) > func(Lambda&& visit) const {
        //return directly in some cases, so complexity is not a problem

        func<N - 1, one>([&visit] {
            do_something1();// depend on the results of func<N - 1, one>
            visit();
        });

        func<N - 1, two>([&visit] {
            do_something2();// depend on the results of func<N - 1, two>
            visit();
        });
    }
    template<int N, Case case_, typename Lambda>
    std::enable_if_t < (0 == N) > func(Lambda&& visit) const {
        visit();
    }
};

int main() {
    loop{}.func<32, one>([] {});

    return 0;
}
```

However, this would not compile because of deep recursion. In my opinion, it is inline and two branches in func which cause the problem. So, is there an efficient way to work around this problem?

Comment: You have `2**32` function calls to visit (and function instanciation)...

Comment: @Jarod42 I think there are 4*32 visit, i.e. for each N and case_.

Comment: Inside a template argument, comparisons are clearer if you add parentheses : `std::enable_if_t < (N>0) >`.

Comment: @user1535111: Jarod is right. There are 4*32 different instantiations, but the lower-level instantiations can be reached by multiple paths. Thus there are indeed 4 billion function calls to consider for inlining.

Answer (score 0):

Inlining can solve runtime complexity. The "return early" also solves runtime complexity. However, the compiler error is because you have compile-time complexity. Even unreachable code has to be compiled.

And this code has massive complexity if the compiler inlines it. Both branches would be inlined, which means that the `// return early` check of `f<31>` in inlined twice in `f<32>`, the `// return early` check of `f<30>` is inlined twice in `f<31>` and thus 4 times in `f<32>`, and thus `f<0>` would be inlined about 4 billion times. No decent compiler should have problems with that; it should just skip the inlining.

The easy solution is to drop `Case` (it's not used anyway) and make `N` a regular variable. A more complex method is to check at runtime whether variable N has some small constant value Nc, and only then call the templatized version of the function. By choosing Nc, you can limit the template instantiation depth.

Comment: Would it be possible in such a case to force the compiler to incrementally instantiate f? As in, first instantiate f<5>, then f<10>, then f<15> and so on, avoiding the exponential increase in inlining functions?

Comment: The instantiation decision stands separate from the inlining decision, so yes you can instantiate `f<5>` but that would not necessarily solve your problem. However, I would consider using a divide-and-conquer algorithm here. Use a lambda that calls `func<N/2>` and pass that to `func<N/2>`(!) (you'll probably need a `if(N%2)` test but that optimizes out for even `N`).